# How to set row color in ng-grid based on a cell value which is a text?

Tags: angularjs, row, ng-grid

I am referring to this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/X4SqsjGtlDOJQrkrYWv6?p=preview
I want to set the color of a row as green if the pedido is "A001".
How should I do this? 
I tried changing the **ng-class, but doesn't seem to work because it is "A001"

Please let me know if I have to change something else

```
var rowTemplate = `
    <div style="height: 100%"
         ng-class="{red: row.getProperty('\pedido\') == C003,
                    green: row.getProperty('\pedido\') == A001}">
       <div ng-style="{'cursor': row.cursor }"
            ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns"
            ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell ">
           <div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}"
                ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }">
           </div>
           <div ng-cell>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always set class = A001
you should change = to ==

```
green: row.getProperty(\'pedido\') = A001
```

change to

```
green: row.getProperty(\'pedido\') == \'A001\'
```

Comment: Here is a new Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/IU2taXJdvGfOg9uSAUmH?p=preview . It doesnt seem to work

Comment: you should add \' in string
green: row.getProperty(\'pedido\') == \'A001\'

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response. But even after making it green: row.getProperty(\'pedido\') == \'A001\' , it doesnt work. Is it the default behavior of ng-grid?

Comment: You can check it in new Plunkr: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/jMKnMwwqYrBAEuS0

Comment: This is working now. Thank You